# Python value error this sheet is too large

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read multiple csv files through pandas.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
files_list=os.listdir('path to csv files')
df=[pd.read_csv(f,sep=';') for f in files_list]
big_df=pd.concat(df)
x=big_df.gropuby(['columnnames']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(name='Count')

writer=pd.excelwriter('filename.xlsx')
x.to_excel(writer,index=False)
writer.close()
```

This gives me value error because my sheet is too large.It has 1250619 rows.How can I save my output in excel

Comment: You cannot.  Excel has an upper limit of 1,048,576 rows.  If you really need Excel output, you will have to reduce the dataset size.  Personally, I don't see the point.  No human being can scroll through a million-row spreadsheet.

Comment: How should i reduce its size?

Comment: Reducing the size basically means losing some data, like exporting a subset of your data. Or alternatively, exporting multiple smaller files. But still, you're better off going with a different format

Comment: But I need to save my output in order to view it

Comment: Do you really need to view all 1 million plus rows, or can you handle your data to provide what you actually need?

Comment: yes I need to view all the rows because it has different ip.addresses which I need

Comment: Do you not have a way to filter out rows programmatically considering you already have the data loaded? If not, as Emmanuel said, split the DataFrame into smaller parts and save them in separate files/sheets or save them in a different file format. For example, csv files don't have a row limit, but you still won't be able to load the full csv file in excel and will need other methods to view it.

Comment: As other have said, you simply cannot use Microsoft Excel due to its row limitation. If you need to visualise the combined data from multiple CSV files, why not use a database then a simple query to reveal the data you're interested in? Also, that's not your code is it?

Comment: Because I dont know how to use sql and this is my code and I have already divided my data into 2 sheets

Comment: *But I need to save my output in order to view it* -- there are lots of ways to save the file without using the Excel file format.  You can write a simple text file, one row per line.  You can write a combined CSV file, and look at the file in a text editor, instead of using Excel.  As we said, you are never going to look at a million rows.  It would be better to filter out the information you need.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.  Excel has an upper limit of 1,048,576 rows.  If you really need Excel output, you will have to reduce the dataset size, or use a different format.